# Homogeneous vector bundles with zero chern classes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, complex-geometry, vector-bundles

We know that a line bundle $L$  on the complex  flag variety $G/P$ is trivial iff $c_1(E) = 0$. But if we have a homogeneous vector bundle $E$ of higher rank, then is it true that $c_i(E) = 0$ $ \forall i$ implies that $E$ is trivial? If not, is there anything analogous we can say about such vector bundles? I apologize if this question is trivial as my Representation theory background isn't that great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take for instance $G/P = Gr(k,n)$, and let 
$$
0 \to U \to V \otimes \mathcal{O} \to Q \to 0
$$
be the tautological exact sequence. Then
$$
c_\bullet(U \oplus Q) = c_\bullet(U) \cdot c_\bullet(Q) = c_\bullet(V \otimes \mathcal{O}) = 1,
$$
but $U \oplus Q$ is a nontrivial vector bundle.

A similar example can be constructed on any flag variety.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I realized after asking this question that it's actually really easy to produce counterexamples: \mathcal{O}(-n) \bigoplus \mathcal{O}(n)  on \mathbf{P}^n  being easy counterexamples. In fact more generally, any homogeneous bundle all of whose weights are  non zero linear combinations of the weights corresponding to the parabolic $P$ will have zero chern classes, but not be trivial. I think this question should be taken off this site: it's too silly.

Comment: Not quite, in fact $c_2(\mathcal{O}(-n) \oplus \mathcal{O}(n)) \ne 0$.

Comment: Yes, you're right, it should be $-n^2$. But whatever, the Chern class formula for homogeneous bundles sees only the weights which aren't  in $P$. So there exist lots of counterexamples.